# Unable to RUN apt-get update in Dockerfile with manual iptables

Tags: docker, dockerfile, iptables, apt

I have an iptables configured on my server. When i try to build my custom docker image with a Dockerfile, I've an error when the Dockerfile trying to update the source list with `RUN apt-get update`:

`W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'`

This is my complete iptables configuration:

```
iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
17977 2949K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/sec burst 5
    6   360 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,2202,2203,9418 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,2202,2203,9418
  811 48660 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x29/0x29
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  enp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x04
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
    0     0 DROP       all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
  131 35525 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  372 23576 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 enp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
16357 3167K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,2202,2203,9418 ctstate ESTABLISHED
  811 48660 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,2202,2203,9418
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:20
  811 48660 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   58 19024 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Without iptables, everything is fine. For information, i have updated the `/etc/default/docker` to use the `DOCKERD="/usr/local/bin/dockerd --iptables=false"`

I didn't understand what is bad in my iptables configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with disabling the `--iptables=false` for docker daemon and with the  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.